# Angels and gentiles

Tags: gentiles, malach-angel

Are there any passages in Rabbinic literature that discuss angels and gentiles?

Are there any statements that suggest that angels were created specifically by God only for Israel and not for the gentiles?

Are there any claims that state that angels only protect Jews and not gentiles?

Thank you in advance. Shalom.

Comment: Even every individual has his own angel, who looks after his interests. Even the bad guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see Rashi 33:8

After Jacob fought with Esav (a non-Jew) Rashi explains that Jacob tells him he saw and fought his guardian angel

> What is to you [the purpose of] all this camp: Who is all this camp
> that I have met, which is yours? That is to say, why is it yours? The
> simple meaning of the verse is [that Esau asked] about those who
> brought the gift. Its midrashic interpretation is that he (Esau)
> encountered groups of angels, who were shoving him and his men and
> asking them, “To whom do you belong?” and they responded, “We belong
> to Esau.” They (the angels) said [to one another], “Hit [them], hit
> [them]!” These [men of Esau] would say, “Leave them alone! He is
> Isaac’s son.” But [the angels] would pay this no heed. [Esau’s men
> then retorted,] “He is Abraham’s grandson.” But they (the angels)
> would pay this no heed. [Esau’s men again retorted,] “He is Jacob’s
> brother.” [The angels] then said to them, “If so, he is one of ours.”
>
> - [from Gen. Rabbah 78: 11]

See Ramban 18:25

There he explains that Israel is directed by Hashem; however, other nations are ruled over by higher powers and above them the angels. Who of course all do the commands of G-d, but Israel has a more direct connection.